# Code to delete rows based on criteria is deleting entire sheet if one of the criteria is a no match

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to delete rows if a cell in column B matches the criteria referenced for sheet "1.0", however when running the code it is deleting the entire sheet if criteria6 is not available. Is there a way to have the code not delete if there is no match and proceed to the next command? Thanks!

```
    'MACRO TO DELETE SYSTEMATIC USERNAMES
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Const ColumntoFilter1 As Integer = 2
    Const FilterCriteria1 As String = "ASH"
    Const FilterCriteria2 As String = "HPD"
    Const FilterCriteria3 As String = "INQUIRY"
    Const FilterCriteria4 As String = "BULKOPS"
    Const FilterCriteria5 As String = "AHIN1"
    Const FilterCriteria6 As String = "LPXP"
    Const FilterCriteria7 As String = "PPI_BATCH"
    Const FilterCriteria8 As String = "REPROCESSOR"

    'DELETES SYSTEM USERNAMES FROM 1.0 TAB
     Set ws = Sheets("1.0")
    'Set the starting position (Top-left most position) of your data range
    Set StartCell = ws.Range("A1")

    'Turn off autofilter in case it's already active
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'Define data table
    Set rngTable = StartCell.CurrentRegion
    'Filter and delete data
    With rngTable
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria1
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete
    End With
    With rngTable
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria2
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete
    End With
    With rngTable
        **.AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria6
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete**
    End With
    'Turn filters off again
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    Set rngTable = Nothing
    Set StartCell = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

    'DELETES SYSTEM USERNAMES FROM 2.0 TAB
    Set ws = Sheets("2.0")
    'Set the starting position (Top-left most position) of your data range
    Set StartCell = ws.Range("A1")

    'Turn off autofilter in case it's already active
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'Define data table
    Set rngTable = StartCell.CurrentRegion
    'Filter and delete data
    With rngTable
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria2
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete
    End With
    With rngTable
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria6
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete
    End With
    With rngTable
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria8
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.delete
    End With
   'Turn filters off again
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    Set rngTable = Nothing
    Set StartCell = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
```

I have tried researching but have not found a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I get multiple pop ups asking to delete entire sheet. I want to avoid that prompt and have it delete just the rows that match the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.  You can filter multiple values in one shot using an array, and reduce your duplicated code by using a sub to run the deletes.

```
Sub Tester()
    'MACRO TO DELETE SYSTEMATIC USERNAMES
    Const ColumntoFilter1 As Integer = 2
    Const FilterCriteria1 As String = "ASH"
    Const FilterCriteria2 As String = "HPD"
    Const FilterCriteria3 As String = "INQUIRY"
    Const FilterCriteria4 As String = "BULKOPS"
    Const FilterCriteria5 As String = "AHIN1"
    Const FilterCriteria6 As String = "LPXP"
    Const FilterCriteria7 As String = "PPI_BATCH"
    Const FilterCriteria8 As String = "REPROCESSOR"
    
    DeleteRows Sheets("1.0").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, 2, _
       Array(FilterCriteria1, FilterCriteria2, FilterCriteria6)

    DeleteRows Sheets("2.0").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, 2, _
       Array(FilterCriteria2, FilterCriteria6, FilterCriteria8)


End Sub

Sub DeleteRows(rng As Range, colNum As Long, arrVals)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=colNum, _
                    Criteria1:=arrVals, _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next 'In case no visible rows, although the
                             ' `Offset(1)` should include a visible row
                             ' below the data being filtered...
                                  
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring error
    End With
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried this but having issue bringing it to run concurrently. I need for it to run together instead of different subs bc i have other codes right after this. There are others that will run this report who are not savvy in excel to run multiple macros. They will get confused.

Comment: You only need to run `Tester` - the other method `DeleteRows` is called from that.